# Apache2 server applies Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to every response EXCEPT XHR

Tags: reactjs, apache2, axios, create-react-app

I’m testing deploying my CRA app using apache httpd. It’s consuming an external API, so I need to configure the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to allow for this.

I’ve added a rule for adding an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the .htaccess file.

.htaccess:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

javascript http request:

```
Axios.get(URL).then(successCallback).catch(errorCallback);
```

The responses to the requests to the server on my localhost have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin set to the correct value; However, the one request it makes to an external API does not seem to have this header at all on the response given that Chrome shows this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at '{URL}’ from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I’ve checked that the headers and rewrite modules are enabled in the httpd.conf. I’ve been through all the various guides on enabling this functionality but haven’t had any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The responses to the requests to the server on my localhost have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin set to the correct value; However, the one request it makes to an external API does not seem to have this header at all on the response

The server on your localhost and the external API are **different servers**.

The configuration file for your local server won't affect the remote server.

You need to configure **that server** to grant permissions with CORS.

Comment: Thanks for responding.
Sorry, I don’t quite understand. My understanding is that the browser generates a request that the server sends. Then the server attaches the CORS header to the response from the external API server and then sends it to the browser.

For example, even if I attempt to get from a public API, GitHub for example, I would still receive the same error. Surely they have configured their servers to allow for CORS?

Comment: No. The browser makes a request to the URL. It doesn't proxy it through some other server.

Comment: "For example, even if I attempt to get from a public API, GitHub for example, I would still receive the same error. Surely they have configured their servers to allow for CORS? " — https://developer.github.com/v3/#cross-origin-resource-sharing — Github say they have. I've no idea why your attempt to use their API failed.

Comment: It seems to have something to do with Axios — making the same request to the GitHub API with fetch works fine. Anything request made with Axios creates a CORS error.

Comment: @JoshSchecker — Well if you want to solve that problem then ask a question, with a [mcve], about it.

Comment: I think I have already. Seems like it is caused by applying adding custom header to the request.
Thanks for your help.